# kill processes started in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I start my app by starting many processes, I use a script (bash) to start it.

- The filemane is : `start.sh` and I use `sudo ./start.sh` to run
- The script in `start.sh` is:

`#!/bin/sh
 sudo p1 > p1.txt && p2 > p2.txt && p3 > p3.txt`

to stop my app I use `ctrl-c` but not all processes stop. I know I could find with `ps aux | less | grep ...`, this seems long and I want to know if there is and easy wait to stop my processes.

**update**
sorry it is this instead (only one **&**)

```
sudo f1/p1.py > logs/p1.txt &  sudo f2/p2.sh > logs/p2.txt & sudo nodemon f3/p3.js > logs/p3.txt
```

Comment: If you have `ps && p2 && p3...`, then you only have one process running at a time. After p1 completes successfully, p2 starts & so on.

Comment: Also, since `start.sh` was started with `sudo`, you don't need to explicitly start `p1` with `sudo`.

Comment: Now, how these individual process reacts to `ctrl+c` (or more correctly, to `SIGINT`) is dependent on how that application is coded. It can handle `SIGINT` and end with success or failure, based on how it is coded. but pressing `ctrl+c` (passing SIGINT) does not mean that process would end. It's usual/common behavior, but it's not mandatory to behave that way.

Comment: you are right about &. I made mistake. Thank for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the PIDs, and set a trap to kill them when signaled or on exit:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - NOT /bin/sh, as this code uses arrays

pids=( )

# define cleanup function
cleanup() {
  for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    kill -0 "$pid" && kill "$pid" # kill process only if it's still running
  done
}

# and set that function to run before we exit, or specifically when we get a SIGTERM
trap cleanup EXIT TERM

sudo f1/p1.py > logs/p1.txt & pids+=( "$!" )
sudo f2/p2.sh > logs/p2.txt & pids+=( "$!" )
sudo nodemon f3/p3.js > logs/p3.txt & pids+=( "$!" )

wait # sleep until all background processes have exited, or a trap fires
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the process name that you start on your script then you can do something like this which kill all the process with that name.

example: Kill skype process

```
pkill skype
```

For more detailed options see `man pkill`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your shell PID (process ID), you can do:

```
pkill -TERM -P PPID
```

where PPID is your shell PID (the subprocesses parent's PID).

Comment: Isn't the shell `pid` normally in `$$` in `bash`?